# TypeError: strided_slice() missing 1 required positional argument: 'strides'

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, nlp, recurrent-neural-network

In My [Repository](https://github.com/joshua-goldman/test) when i run the file comp.py i get the following error

```
TypeError: strided_slice() missing 1 required positional argument: 'strides'
```

I used strided_slices in reader.py. I don't know why this error is arising. Any help would be great.

Comment: I got this code from the tensorflow models

Comment: which version of tensorflow you are using?

Comment: I ran the command tf.__version__ and got the output 0.12.0

Comment: so its a version problem. you need tf version>1, you can install `tensorflow==1.2.0`